# matplotlib used in parallel crashes because of cache files (tex-renderin)

Tags: python, caching, matplotlib, latex

I execute matplotlib in parallel with MPI where each rank executes a python script which uses matplotlib.

My problem is that while using only one process everything works fine, and as soon as I have multiple processes the "~/.cache/matplotlib" files of the latex pipeline in matplotlib are accessed concurrently which results in errors (reading writing, what ever...?). I am not quite sure but I think the error lies in this `.cache` files which get accessed concurrently?

Is there any possibilty to tell matplotlib to use another cache folder (one per process). That would be awesome and I think would solve the problem.
Or is matplotlib not able to be used in parallel..., or can we somehow modify the python state such that matplotlib does not look in ~/.config but in a user defined location for each process .

**Update:**
I have seen in `texmanager.py` in matpllotlib source:
there is a command :

```
mpl.get_cachedir()
```

but how to set the cache dir, there is no `mpl.set_cachedir`.

**Output of one run: (Not really usefull)**

```
Exception occured here: LaTeX was not able to process the following string:
b'velocity histograms'
Here is the full report generated by LaTeX: 

No latex error report available.
====================================================================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zfmgpu/Desktop/Repository/SimulationFramework/SourceCode/Projects/SimulationFramework/Simulations/JobScripts/JobGenerator/jobGenerators/jobGeneratorMPI/generatorToolPipeline/scripts/generalPipeline/generalProcess.py", line 33, in main
    process.doProcessing()
  File "/home/zfmgpu/Desktop/Repository/SimulationFramework/SourceCode/Projects/SimulationFramework/Simulations/JobScripts/JobGenerator/jobGenerators/jobGeneratorMPI/generatorToolPipeline/scripts/civPipeline/accivCorrelator.py", line 43, in doProcessing
    self._processFrame(frame)
  File "/home/zfmgpu/Desktop/Repository/SimulationFramework/SourceCode/Projects/SimulationFramework/Simulations/JobScripts/JobGenerator/jobGenerators/jobGeneratorMPI/generatorToolPipeline/scripts/civPipeline/accivCorrelator.py", line 137, in _processFrame
    plotter(options)
  File "/home/zfmgpu/Desktop/Repository/SimulationFramework/SourceCode/Projects/SimulationFramework/Simulations/CIVJobs/Experiments-3Passes/scripts/accivPlotting/plotVelocities.py", line 559, in plot
    fig.savefig(outFileName)
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1470, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2194, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 569, in print_jpg
    buf, size = self.print_to_buffer()
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 540, in print_to_buffer
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 469, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1011, in draw
    self.tight_layout(renderer, **self._tight_parameters)
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1654, in tight_layout
    rect=rect)
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/tight_layout.py", line 352, in get_tight_layout_figure
    pad=pad, h_pad=h_pad, w_pad=w_pad)
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/tight_layout.py", line 129, in auto_adjust_subplotpars
    tight_bbox_raw = union([ax.get_tightbbox(renderer) for ax in subplots])
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/tight_layout.py", line 129, in <listcomp>
    tight_bbox_raw = union([ax.get_tightbbox(renderer) for ax in subplots])
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 3252, in get_tightbbox
    bb.append(self.title.get_window_extent(renderer))
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 741, in get_window_extent
    bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 320, in _get_layout
    ismath=ismath)
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 223, in get_text_width_height_descent
    renderer=self)
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py", line 670, in get_text_width_height_descent
    dvifile = self.make_dvi(tex, fontsize)
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py", line 417, in make_dvi
    report))
RuntimeError: LaTeX was not able to process the following string:
b'velocity histograms'
Here is the full report generated by LaTeX: 

No latex error report available.
```

**Output second run:
Here the second process crashed because of this exception...?**

```
====================================================================
Exception occured here: _image_module::readpng: error reading PNG header
====================================================================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zfmgpu/Desktop/Repository/SimulationFramework/SourceCode/Projects/SimulationFramework/Simulations/JobScripts/JobGenerator/jobGenerators/jobGeneratorMPI/generatorToolPipeline/scripts/generalPipeline/generalProcess.py", line 33, in main
    process.doProcessing()
  File "/home/zfmgpu/Desktop/Repository/SimulationFramework/SourceCode/Projects/SimulationFramework/Simulations/JobScripts/JobGenerator/jobGenerators/jobGeneratorMPI/generatorToolPipeline/scripts/civPipeline/accivCorrelator.py", line 43, in doProcessing
    self._processFrame(frame)
  File "/home/zfmgpu/Desktop/Repository/SimulationFramework/SourceCode/Projects/SimulationFramework/Simulations/JobScripts/JobGenerator/jobGenerators/jobGeneratorMPI/generatorToolPipeline/scripts/civPipeline/accivCorrelator.py", line 137, in _processFrame
    plotter(options)
  File "/home/zfmgpu/Desktop/Repository/SimulationFramework/SourceCode/Projects/SimulationFramework/Simulations/CIVJobs/Experiments-3Passes/scripts/accivPlotting/plotVelocities.py", line 559, in plot
    fig.savefig(outFileName)
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1470, in savefig
    self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2194, in print_figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 569, in print_jpg
    buf, size = self.print_to_buffer()
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 540, in print_to_buffer
    FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 469, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1079, in draw
    func(*args)
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2092, in draw
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1119, in draw
    tick.draw(renderer)
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 249, in draw
    self.label1.draw(renderer)
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 59, in draw_wrapper
    draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py", line 581, in draw
    self._fontproperties, angle, mtext=mtext)
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 250, in draw_tex
    Z = texmanager.get_grey(s, size, self.dpi)
  File "/opt/python3.4env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py", line 579, in get_grey
    X = read_png(os.path.join(self.texcache, pngfile))
RuntimeError: _image_module::readpng: error reading PNG header
```

Answer (score 4):

It was so easy:

Just set the environment variable, e.g. :

```
export MPLCONFIGDIR="./Process0/temp/matpllotlib"
```

and all tex cache files go into this folder :-)
and now parallel plotting works :-)